# Word to describe gossip/chit chat about film and film stars

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to describe people who constantly gossip about film and film stars.

For eg. *They were discussing trivial matters like ____ about film and film stars*

Please feel to free to change the structure of the sentence if needed.

Comment: What's wrong with 'gossip'?

Comment: I feel that gossip is just a general word. A word that describes gossip about film would be suitable in my case.

Comment: How about *film-gossip*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest **"a tattletale cinephile"** or **"a gossiping moviegoer"**?

> [**cinephile**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cinephile) - "a person who loves films and cinema"
>
> [**moviegoer**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moviegoer) - "a person who goes to see motion pictures frequently"
>
> - "They were **tattletale cinephiles**, discussing trivial matters about films and film stars"
> - "They were **gossiping moviegoers**, babbling trivial matters about films and film stars."

Answer (score 2):

*drivel*

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drivel) gives " 2. childish, silly, or meaningless talk or thinking; nonsense; twaddle."